# How to compute the probability that two buses arrive in opposite order given their scheduled arrival time?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

Let's assume that we have two buses A and B which arrive at a depot at 5:05pm and 5:10pm respectively. Thus A should arrive before B, but it might well happen that A arrives **after** B. I want to compute this probability, i.e. the probability that A arrives before B. In other terms, given the time difference of arrival, what is the probability they arrive in the opposite order?

How can we simply model this problem and what parameters do I need to estimate?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know anything about the probability distribution of the arrival time [of a bus, either A or B]? Maybe it's a normal distribution?

Comment: Let's assume for convenience it's a normal distribution, can we model something easy out of this hypothesis? Although, it's probably not the case, it should be skewed to the right.

Comment: If we set the "time coordinate system" so that $t=0$ corresponds to 5:05 pm, (units are one minute, so that $t= 1$ corresponds to 05:06 pm) and assume that the bus A's arrival time $X$ follows the normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$: $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Now, the question that we have, is: What is the probability that $X> 5$?? Do you know how to calculate this, for example?

Comment: I think I got it...
If X is the time of arrival of the bus A and Y is the time of arrival of the bus B and both follow normal distributions, then we need to understand the difference Y - X. This is again a normal distribution with mean t and variance 2 sigma squared. Thus we now need to compute the probability that Y-X is less than 0. This is "easy"!

Comment: About modelling issue: For the arrival time, you should put exponential / gamma distribution into your considerations. These two are very common in modelling the arrival time (of Poisson process). The have positive support, which unlike normal which also have negative support (of course practically you may truncate it). And one more thing you should put into consideration is that the dependency structure between the two buses - are they independent or not.